# Add an empty row/bean to editable grid in Vaadin 8

Tags: java, vaadin8

I have a `grid` with editable columns, with data lazy loaded from a `REST API`, now I want to add an empty row with editing enabled on that row on an `Add` button `clickEvent` in Vaadin 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround I found is to add an empty bean to the `list` that we retrieve from `REST`, do a `grid.setItems(list)` and then do `grid.refreshAll()`.